# Sharepoint 2013 adding three dash to look list dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, lookup

Microsoft sharepoint 2013 has created an entry with three dashes (---) to list when linked to separate list from look up - how can I remove those --- from list so individuals are able to select when creating new list entries.  See example below;

[list example with ---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51aXG.png)